# How to optimize a query that is a join of 2 very similar queries but with different aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT OBJ_DESC_ERRORS.description, OBJ_DESC_ERRORS.object, OBJ_DESC_ERRORS.count_errors, OBJ_ERRORS.count_total FROM 

(SELECT `metrics_event`.`description`, `metrics_event`.`object`, COUNT(`metrics_event`.`id`) AS `count_errors` FROM `metrics_event` 
INNER JOIN `metrics_session` ON (`metrics_event`.`session_id` = `metrics_session`.`id`) 

WHERE (`metrics_session`.`training_id` = 4 AND NOT (`metrics_session`.`completed_at` IS NULL) ) 
GROUP BY `metrics_event`.`description`, `metrics_event`.`object` ORDER BY `count_errors` DESC ) as OBJ_DESC_ERRORS

JOIN

(SELECT  `metrics_event`.`object`, COUNT(`metrics_event`.`id`) AS `count_total` FROM `metrics_event` 
INNER JOIN `metrics_session` ON (`metrics_event`.`session_id` = `metrics_session`.`id`) 

WHERE (`metrics_session`.`training_id` = 4 AND NOT (`metrics_session`.`completed_at` IS NULL) ) 
GROUP BY `metrics_event`.`object` ORDER BY `count_total` DESC ) as OBJ_ERRORS

ON OBJ_DESC_ERRORS.object = OBJ_ERRORS.object
```

which produces the following result:
[image: Query output]

As you can see I'm basically running the same query twice. The reason for that is that I need to have that count_errors broken down by each aggregation of object + description, but I also need the count_total to be only aggregated by object. This was the way I could think of. Now I'd like to know if this is the best I can do or if it can be optimized even further.

If so I have no clue how. Googling and searching similar topics on this is difficult because the optimization task depends on the query itself, so keywords here didn't help me much.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the inner `ORDER BYs`; they do nothing useful.

Rewrite the query something like this:

```
SELECT 
    me.description,
    me.object,
    SUM(...) AS count_errors,
    SUM(...) AS count_total
FROM  `metrics_event` AS me
INNER JOIN  `metrics_session` AS ms  ON (me.`session_id` = ms.`id`)
WHERE ms.`training_id` = 4
      ms.`completed_at` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  me.`description`, me.`object`
ORDER BY  `count_total` DESC
```

Since a boolean expression evaluates as 1 for TRUE, else 0, devise the argument to `SUM()` to be a boolean expression that provides the desired COUNT.

Comment: The second SUM (count_total) is tricky here because it needs to be a sum of count_errors but grouped by object.So here is the query with conditions:  SELECT 
    me.description,
    me.object,
    SUM(me.error_severity > 0) AS count_errors,
    SUM(me.error_severity > -1) AS count_total 
    FROM  `metrics_event` AS me
INNER JOIN  `metrics_session` AS ms  ON (me.`session_id` = ms.`id`)
WHERE ms.`training_id` = 4 AND
      ms.`completed_at` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  me.`description`, me.`object`
ORDER BY  `count_total` DESC.   But I'm not sure how to add that condition case to count_total